# Show content filter by user on extended CB

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to show a **content only post by the current** logged in user on a ListView but the answer here : [How to make generic ListView only show user's listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725617/how-to-make-generic-listview-only-show-users-listing) does not solve my problem because my ListView used 4 models

**views.py**

```
class DashboardListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = Links
template_name = 'dashboard/home.html'
context_object_name ='links_list'
paginate_by = 15

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['dashboard_list']= Dashboard.objects.all()[:15]
    context['todo_list']= Todo.objects.all().order_by('-pk')[:15]
    context['todo_complete']= Todo.objects.all().count()
    context['PasswordUsername_list']= PasswordUsername.objects.all()
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

I tried to add a **get_context** and a **get_query_set** but it's hiding only the link model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to another post

In the **views.py**

```
class DashboardListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = Links
template_name = 'dashboard/home.html'
context_object_name ='links_list'
paginate_by = 15

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(author=self.request.user) 

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['dashboard_list']= Dashboard.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)[:15]
    context['todo_list']= Todo.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-pk')[:15]
    context['PasswordUsername_list']= PasswordUsername.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
    return context
```

You have to filter the context using "yourmodel.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)"
And a query_set

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```